# LatitudeLongitude to LongitudeLatitude string. Swap coordinates in string

Tags: javascript, algorithm, coordinates, openlayers

OpenLayers accepts coordinates in format Longitude-Latitude, and I want user to enter in  Latitude-Longitude format.
User inputs coordinates as a string in input field.

It is easy to swap if we have point:

```
var coo = ‘50, 30’;
OpenLayers.LonLat(JSON.parse(‘[‘+coo+’]’)[1], JSON.parse(‘[‘+coo+’]’)[0]);
```

But in case of line format:

```
var coo = ‘50 30, 55 35’;
```

It becomes a pain. Maybe there is a ready solutions for that case? I need to convert string from `x1 y1, x2 y2, ...` to `y1 x1, y2 x2, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your coordinates string into an array, reverse your coordinate pairs (from lat-lon to lon-lat) and transform it again into an array:

```
let cooLonLat = coo
    .replaceAll(', ', ',')
    .split(',')
    .map(pair => pair.split(' ').reverse().join(' '))
    .join()
    .replaceAll(',', ', ')
```

Check fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lfcb9pak/

Comment: I already made another workable approach with JSON, but thanks